# Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account

Tags: solidity, hardhat, uniswap

I have this constructor:

```
    constructor (uint160 sqrtPriceX96_) {
        _rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal;
        _ISwapRouter = ISwapRouter(0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564);
        _IUniswapV3Factory = IUniswapV3Factory(0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984); //Uniswap-V3 for Uniswap arbitrum
        _IPoolInitializer = IPoolInitializer(0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88); //Uniswap-V3 for Uniswap arbitrum
        WETH = 0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6; //WETH for Uniswap arbitrum
        _INonfungiblepositionmanager = INonfungiblePositionManager(0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88); //Uniswap-V3 for Uniswap arbitru
        addressThis = address(this);
        token0 = addressThis;
        token1 = WETH; //WETH adress for Arbitrum
        fee = 3000;
        _sqrtPriceX96 = sqrtPriceX96_;    

        poolAddress = _IUniswapV3Factory.getPool(token0, token1, fee);
        if (poolAddress == address(0)) {
            if(token0 > token1){
                address temp = token0;
                token0 = token1;
                token1 = temp;
            }
            _IPoolInitializer.createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary(token0, token1, fee, _sqrtPriceX96);
        }
        
        //exclude owner and this contract from fee
        _isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[addressThis] = true;
        
        emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _tTotal);
    }
```

Here's the imports:

```
import "./utils/SafeMath.sol";
import "./utils/Context.sol";
import "./utils/Address.sol";
import "./utils/Ownable.sol";
import "./interfaces/IBEP20.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Factory.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Pool.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IPoolInitializer.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/INonfungiblePositionManager.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/libraries/FixedPoint96.sol";
```

The variables declaration:

```
    uint256 tokenId;
    IUniswapV3Factory _IUniswapV3Factory;
    ISwapRouter _ISwapRouter;
    IPoolInitializer _IPoolInitializer;
    INonfungiblePositionManager _INonfungiblepositionmanager;
    bool hasPosition;
```

I'm facing this error:

`error: SolidityError: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account`

The addresses from goerli are correct. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

I was deploying in the wrong network.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when you try to call via the wrong network

Possible fixes

1. Check if you're on the same network as the contract's deployed network.
2. Check the spelling of function you're calling